# Keyboard and Touchpad temporarily deactivate, all else working

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

This has started happening several times today. Lasting for 20 seconds or so, the keyboard and touchpad on my Macbook Pro stop responding to inputs. Everything else is working fine and I can see movement on my screen. I'm running the latest Mountain Lion, and I think this may have something to do with it:

```
1/10/12 12:58:01.173 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Session 100032 created
1/10/12 12:58:03.363 PM mdworker[3501]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
1/10/12 12:58:03.381 PM mdworker[3499]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
1/10/12 12:58:03.397 PM mdworker[3500]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
1/10/12 12:58:03.451 PM sandboxd[3502]: ([3501]) mdworker(3501) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
1/10/12 12:58:03.457 PM sandboxd[3502]: ([3499]) mdworker(3499) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
1/10/12 12:58:03.464 PM sandboxd[3502]: ([3500]) mdworker(3500) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
1/10/12 12:58:03.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(3502) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
1/10/12 12:58:21.779 PM postfix/qmgr[1368]: warning: connect to transport private/retry: Connection refused
1/10/12 12:58:49.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10675.120   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:58:55.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10681.122   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:01.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10687.126   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:07.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10693.129   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:19.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10705.134   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:20.647 PM Google Chrome Helper[3659]: Unsure about the internals of CFAllocator but going to patch them anyway. If there is a crash inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, please report it at http://crbug.com/117476 . If there is a crash and it is NOT inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, it is NOT RELATED. DO NOT REPORT IT THERE but rather FILE A NEW BUG.
1/10/12 12:59:20.887 PM Google Chrome Helper[3659]: bootstrap_look_up2 failed with 0x44c
1/10/12 12:59:20.888 PM Google Chrome Helper[3659]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
1/10/12 12:59:25.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10711.136   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:25.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10711.137   IOUSBCompositeDriver[0xffffff8019c10600](IOUSBDevice) GetFullConfigDescriptor(0) returned NULL
1/10/12 12:59:31.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10717.139   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:34.470 PM Google Chrome Helper[3660]: Unsure about the internals of CFAllocator but going to patch them anyway. If there is a crash inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, please report it at http://crbug.com/117476 . If there is a crash and it is NOT inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, it is NOT RELATED. DO NOT REPORT IT THERE but rather FILE A NEW BUG.
1/10/12 12:59:35.245 PM Google Chrome Helper[3660]: bootstrap_look_up2 failed with 0x44c
1/10/12 12:59:35.245 PM Google Chrome Helper[3660]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
1/10/12 12:59:37.127 PM iTunes[3271]: tid:c07 - error getting plugin interface for device: 0xe00002be
1/10/12 12:59:37.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    10723.141   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff80161fe000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfa, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 0)
1/10/12 12:59:40.906 PM imagent[523]: [Warning] XMPPNodeStream: error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out" occurred on input
1/10/12 12:59:40.916 PM imagent[523]: [Warning] XMPPConnection: Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out"
1/10/12 12:59:49.477 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Killing auth hosts
1/10/12 12:59:49.477 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Session 100028 destroyed
1/10/12 1:00:00.832 PM launchctl[3666]: launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
1/10/12 1:00:00.937 PM launchctl[3674]: launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
1/10/12 1:00:01.422 PM Google Chrome Helper[3675]: Unsure about the internals of CFAllocator but going to patch them anyway. If there is a crash inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, please report it at http://crbug.com/117476 . If there is a crash and it is NOT inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, it is NOT RELATED. DO NOT REPORT IT THERE but rather FILE A NEW BUG.
1/10/12 1:00:01.759 PM Google Chrome Helper[3675]: bootstrap_look_up2 failed with 0x44c
1/10/12 1:00:01.759 PM Google Chrome Helper[3675]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
1/10/12 1:00:02.799 PM Google Chrome Helper[3676]: Unsure about the internals of CFAllocator but going to patch them anyway. If there is a crash inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, please report it at http://crbug.com/117476 . If there is a crash and it is NOT inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, it is NOT RELATED. DO NOT REPORT IT THERE but rather FILE A NEW BUG.
1/10/12 1:00:06.034 PM Google Chrome Helper[3676]: bootstrap_look_up2 failed with 0x44c
1/10/12 1:00:06.034 PM Google Chrome Helper[3676]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
1/10/12 1:00:41.222 PM mdworker[3685]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
1/10/12 1:00:41.229 PM mdworker[3687]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
1/10/12 1:00:41.236 PM mdworker[3686]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
1/10/12 1:00:41.320 PM sandboxd[3688]: ([3685]) mdworker(3685) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
1/10/12 1:00:41.326 PM sandboxd[3688]: ([3687]) mdworker(3687) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
1/10/12 1:00:41.333 PM sandboxd[3688]: ([3686]) mdworker(3686) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
1/10/12 1:00:41.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(3688) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
1/10/12 1:00:59.527 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.adobe.fpsaud[3692]) Exited with code: 210
1/10/12 1:01:40.905 PM imagent[523]: [Warning] XMPPNodeStream: error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out" occurred on input
1/10/12 1:01:40.914 PM imagent[523]: [Warning] XMPPConnection: Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out"
1/10/12 1:01:43.707 PM assistantd[3700]: <Error>: Session - Connection error: <ADAceConnection: 0x7f8a91c38910> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out"
1/10/12 1:01:43.715 PM assistantd[3700]: <Error>: Daemon - Session Error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out"
1/10/12 1:02:08.402 PM Dock[492]: no information back from LS about running process
```

Comment: this [particular log entry](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4352126?start=0&tstart=0) doesn't seem to have to do with your problem; it is related to Spotlight and I have these same messages without my keyboard freezing. can you post more logs entries?

Comment: I've posted a more complete log of what happened during that issue, but I suspect there are too many suspects to choose from.

Comment: Which model MacBook Pro? 2010? MacBookPro5,2 here.

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/35970/8546) to [Timeouts in AppleUSBEHCI - how can I find out what is causing this?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35927/8546) may help you to identify devices affected by timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my older MacBook Pro a few years back. The likely culprit isn't software (though you could try using an external keyboard/mouse and attempt to reproduce) but hardware. The top case's USB connection is likely failing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this on my 13" MacBook Pro early 2011. The cause was a solder failure in the Airport/WiFi ribbon cable.

Diagnosis steps:

1. boot up the MacBook on a solid, flat surface
2. open the Applications > Utilities > Console.app
3. wait for the console messages to stop
4. pick up the MacBook as you normally do. In particular, experiment with pressure in the center of the bottom of the MacBook. This is where several ribbon cables connect to the logic board.
5. watch the console; if you start seeing `AppleUSBEHCI` timeout messages then you have tweaked the hardware somehow to induce the problem
6. open up the System Report; select `USB` and see if any devices are missing. In my case, `Bluetooth USB Host Controller` disappeared after I picked up my MacBook, so this pointed to the USB/WiFi connector

Workaround: once you have the MacBook on a stable surface, you can usually restore trackpad/keyboard function by plugging something into the USB port (USB stick, mouse, etc...)

Fix: [replace the Bluetooth/WiFi ribbon cable](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+AirPort-Bluetooth+Cable+Replacement/5162) (in my case; you may have a different failed cable).